# taskkill cant kill a nodejs task

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, batch-file

Im trying to kill a nodejs task by pid with `taskkill /F /pid`. while the stdout says the task-killing was successful, the window is still running. any other commands of "fixes"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
kill -9 2534 // Here 2534 is PID
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.